# MacOS - Need to stop Mouse Movement to Drag Text

Tags: macos, ventura

I've been using a Macbook for a while as my daily driver and it's been a pleasant experience so far. However, the one thing that I've found the most annoying is whenever I drag text.

I've looked this up and it appears that it's been categorized as "Text Drag Delay" but I don't necessarily find this to be the case.

I've looked in to the manual terminal prompts with the code:

```
defaults write -g NSDragAndDropTextDelay -int 100
```

But it still doesn't feel as smooth as I'd like to be. I've changed this to 0, 10, 200 and others, it feels the same.

I've also tried the Tinkertool and it doesn't change it. I did restart the system to check if this could be affecting the edits but it felt the same.

Essentially, whenever I highlight a Text, I have to **stop all movements** while holding down the left mouse button so that I can drag it.

If I move my mouse even the slightest, it will select those parts of the text instead of dragging. So I think that the issue isn't primarily with the delay, but rather the OS selecting the text instead of dragging it. This obviously isn't the case with Windows or Linux.

If anyone can give advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What mouse are you using? I use a trackpad, but can't replicate a problem with movement interrupting the 'change' to drag.

Comment: I can't repro this either, with a mouse & delay set to 100